# passing request header information to app.get

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to pass request information, such as HOST header value, on to app.get?

My application requires that a particular host is present, so when I call it normally like this:

app.get("foo")

Specifically, I want to override the

```
request.env["HTTP_HOST"]
```

value.

tia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this help... I've seen code like the following:

```
app.call({
  "HTTP_HOST"=>"...",
  "SCRIPT_NAME" => "",
  "PATH_INFO"=>"/lala/#{lala_id}/",
  "QUERY_STRING" => "",
  "SERVER_NAME" => "",
  "SERVER_PORT" => "80",
  "REQUEST_METHOD"=>"GET",
  "rack.input" => StringIO.new
})
```

You might be able to still use `.get` and just pass HTTP_HOST as an option like above?

Answer (score 9):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9827985/72176):

The method docs for **.get** are here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

You can do something like:

```
  app.get('/foo', nil, {'HTTP_HOST' => "bar.com"})
```

Comment: And of course you don't need to know the path if you know the route: `app.get(app.foo_path, nil, {'HTTP_HOST' => "bar.com"})`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm wondering how the docs are helpful here though, as the `{'HTTP_HOST' => "bar.com"}` part is literally undocumented. At least `**args` isn't helpful to me.