# How to set request headers in rspec request spec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, testing, rspec

In the controller spec, I can set http accept header like this:

```
request.accept = "application/json"
```

but in the request spec, "request" object is nil. So how can I do it here?

The reason I want to set http accept header to json is so I can do this:

```
get '/my/path'
```

instead of this

```
get '/my/path.json'
```

Answer (score 139):

You should be able to specify HTTP headers as the third argument to your get() method as described here:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get

and here

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/Session.html#method-i-process

So, you can try something like this:

```
get '/my/path', nil, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json"}
```

Comment: We needed to use 'HTTP_ACCEPT':

    `get '/my/path', nil, {'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json"}`

Comment: NOTE: This is for integration testing, similar to comment below, in rspec-rails controller tests, you would use:     request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] =

Comment: Small gotcha that I ran into because I am silly: The header keys have to be Strings. Symbols will not show up.

Comment: @ajmurmann Now symbols work: "Authorization" header can be `:authorization`.

Comment: This is correct for generic headers, but if you're only trying to specify a JSON format with a rails controller like the OP is then `get(:action, format: :json)` should do the trick

Comment: New RSspec 3 syntax would be like `get my_resource_path, params: {}, headers: { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json" }`
`

Comment: Thanks @CyrilDuchon-Doris, yours was the only correct solution I've been able to find in order to set an auth header.

Answer (score 40):

I used this in Test::Unit:

```
@request.env['HTTP_ACCEPT'] = "*/*, application/youtube-client"
get :index
```

Comment: Similarly, as Alex Soto notes in a comment on another answer, in rspec-rails controller tests, you can use: request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT"]

Comment: thanks a lot dude, only example that worked for me on an old 2.3 app with `ActionController::TestCase`

Comment: +1 I tried using a key named `Cookie` in the headers hash (because that's what my browser sends), but it didn't work. Then I did `request.keys` and saw a key named `HTTP_COOKIE`. Using that worked. They really should document this better.

Comment: It really works! I also found that answer in https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/65

Comment: @Sytse Sijbrandij Nobody asked about Test::Unit. Question asked about rspec.

Answer (score 30):

I'm adding this here, as I got majorly stuck trying to do this in Rails 5.1.rc1

The get method signature is slightly different now.

You need to specify the options after the path as keyword arguments, i.e.

`get /some/path, headers: {'ACCEPT' => 'application/json'}`

FYI, the full set of keywords arguments are:

`params: {}, headers: {}, env: {}, xhr: false, as: :symbol`

Answer (score 23):

This is working for controller specs, not request specs:

```
request.headers["My Header"] = "something"
```

Comment: This worked for me, it depends on how are you retrieving the headers, if you are using `request.headers` or `request.env`

Comment: Note: This is for controller tests, not integration tests mentioned in the question.

Comment: didn't work for integration tests. Works with controller tests, however.

Answer (score 11):

With RSpec 3 you can use the following syntax

```
get my_resource_path, params: {}, headers: { 'HTTP_ACCEPT' => "application/json" }
```

As described [in the official Rspec documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/request-specs/request-spec) (the link points to v3.7)

Comment: Sweet. Just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Won't work in a controller spec.

Comment: relishapp is _not_ the official documentation and is offline because of IP issues between the original developer (and that of Cucumber) and it's current owners. See https://mattwynne.net/new-beginning

Answer (score 10):

Using rspec with `Rack::Test::Methods`

```
header 'X_YOUR_HEADER_VAR', 'val'
get '/path'
```

The header var will come through as `X-Your-Header-Var`

Comment: Note: this is for `Test::Unit`, not for RSpec.

Comment: its indicating rspec

Comment: Yeah. In rspec it raises `ndefined method 'header'` error for me.

Answer (score 9):

I have to set up headers separately

```
request.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"
```

Trying sending it via get/delete/.... is complete garbage in rails4 and causing pain in my head because it is never send as header but as parameter.

```
{"Accept" => "application/json"}
```

Comment: Does this really provide an answer to the OP question ? If it is a new question, it is a better idea to open up a new question.

Comment: This is working for controller specs: request.headers["Accept"] = "application/json"

This is working for request specs: get path, headers: {"Accept" => "application/json"}

Answer (score 8):

To send both `xhr: true` and headers, I had to do e.g.:

```
my_headers = { "HTTP_ACCEPT": "application/json" }
get my_path, xhr: true, headers: my_headers
```

Comment: Here's the source code on GitHub: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/e11a62a9fea6f94d607cfa82fa41cdb690fa0294/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb#L58

Comment: Shouldn't `headers =` be `my_headers =` ?

Comment: Fixed. Thanks @webaholik.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
get :index, :format => 'json'
```

Comment: Not sure, but probably works because the rails is looking for .format for that route; this happened to work for me too.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this just adds `format=json` as a query param. Not the same as a header field.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was already answered but in case you want to POST something to another action you have to do this:

```
post :save, {format: :json, application: {param1: "test", param2: "test"}}
```