# How to add `headers` to my get `request`.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

How to add `headers` to my get `request`.

```
it "can find an account" do 
    get "/accounts/#{@acc.id}/", headers # like the token or whatever your api needs
end
```

Below is my `controller` method where i am passing the token, now how would i `append` this to my `get request`.

```
Account.find(id: @acc.id, authorization: @auth_token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `request.env` to set the header

```
it "can find an account" do 
   request.env['AUTH_TOKEN'] = "token"
   get "/accounts/#{@acc.id}/"
end
```

Comment: Also, see more methods discussed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654465/how-to-set-request-headers-in-rspec-request-spec

Answer (score 1):

You can send the headers as the **third** parameter to `get`:

```
get "/accounts/#{@acc.id}/", nil, {'AUTH_TOKEN' => 'token'}.
```

See the documentation for [get](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers.html#method-i-get) for more info.